# Accounts onCreateUser not working as expected Meteor

Tags: facebook, meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-accounts

I'm using a customized UI for logging into facebook. This works perfectly without the `Accounts.onCreateUser` function. Even though I don't touch the `profile` object in the `Accounts.onCreateUser` function, the UI doesn't show the logged in User name.

[image: blank user name]

this happens when i use the `onCreateUser`, this is the code that i use in that function.

```
Balance.insert({
    userID: user._id,
    coin : 0
});
console.log('balance working');

return user;
```

without `onCreateUser` , works fine. screenshot below.

[image: working]

and the `blaze` property is `{{currentUser.profile.name}}`

Comment: Function name is actually `onCreateUser` (http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_oncreateuser) but you wrote `onCreate` is it a typo?

Comment: I used `onCreateUser`, just missed the full function name here, thus edited the post ,@Guillaume

Comment: Can you give more code, e.g. the full `onCreateUser` definition and how/where it's called. Do you have an example page where this can be tested?